# First Response Kit is missing sp_AskBrent

Tags: tools, sp-askbrent

I just downloaded the First Responder kit. Unfortunately, the 'sp_AskBrent' was not included in the download.  How can I get it to complete the kit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sp_AskBrent was renamed to sp_BlitzFirst.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/06/first-responder-kit-updated-sp_askbrent-now-sp_blitzfirst/